# Vaadin Spring Addon NotSerializableException for XmlWebApplicationContext even with transient ApplicationContext UI's member

Tags: java, spring, serialization, vaadin

I am integrating Spring into Vaadin and thanks to the Vaadin Spring addon and to this wiki: https://vaadin.com/wiki?p_p_id=36&p_p_lifecycle=0&p_p_state=normal&p_p_mode=view&p_p_col_id=row-1&p_p_col_pos=2&p_p_col_count=4&_36_struts_action=%2Fwiki%2Fview&p_r_p_185834411_nodeName=vaadin.com+wiki&p_r_p_185834411_title=I+-+Getting+started+with+Vaadin+Spring I was actually able to do it.

However when I restart Tomcat and the Vaadin application is restarted I get the following `NotSerializableException` complaining about Spring's `XmlWebApplicationContext`:

```
SEVERE: Exception loading sessions from persistent storage
java.io.WriteAbortedException: writing aborted; java.io.NotSerializableException: org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1355)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:1993)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1918)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1801)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1351)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:371)
    at java.util.LinkedList.readObject(LinkedList.java:1149)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeReadObject(ObjectStreamClass.java:1017)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1896)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1801)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1351)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:1993)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadObject(ObjectInputStream.java:501)
    at com.vaadin.server.VaadinSession.readObject(VaadinSession.java:1443)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeReadObject(ObjectStreamClass.java:1017)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1896)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1801)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1351)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:371)
    at org.apache.catalina.session.StandardSession.doReadObject(StandardSession.java:1634)
    at org.apache.catalina.session.StandardSession.readObjectData(StandardSession.java:1099)
    at org.apache.catalina.session.StandardManager.doLoad(StandardManager.java:261)
    at org.apache.catalina.session.StandardManager.load(StandardManager.java:180)
    at org.apache.catalina.session.StandardManager.startInternal(StandardManager.java:460)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5213)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1409)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1399)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.io.NotSerializableException: org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1184)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(ObjectOutputStream.java:1548)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1509)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1432)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1178)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:348)
    at java.util.LinkedList.writeObject(LinkedList.java:1131)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeWriteObject(ObjectStreamClass.java:988)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1496)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1432)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1178)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(ObjectOutputStream.java:1548)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1509)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1432)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1178)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:348)
    at org.apache.catalina.session.StandardSession.doWriteObject(StandardSession.java:1710)
    at org.apache.catalina.session.StandardSession.writeObjectData(StandardSession.java:1116)
    at org.apache.catalina.session.StandardManager.doUnload(StandardManager.java:401)
    at org.apache.catalina.session.StandardManager.unload(StandardManager.java:320)
    at org.apache.catalina.session.StandardManager.stopInternal(StandardManager.java:487)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.stop(LifecycleBase.java:232)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.stopInternal(StandardContext.java:5409)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.stop(LifecycleBase.java:232)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StopChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1425)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StopChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1414)
    ... 4 more
```

Actually the code is really simple (based on the tutorial and some other Spring features):

Here is the UI class:

```
package com.example.vaadinwithspring;

//...

@SpringUI("")
@Theme("valo")
@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class MyUI extends UI {

    private transient ApplicationContext appContext;

    @Override
    protected void init(VaadinRequest vaadinRequest) {
        final VerticalLayout layout = new VerticalLayout();
        layout.setMargin(true);
        setContent(layout);

        UserService service = getUserService(vaadinRequest);
        User user = service.getUser();
        String userName = user.getName();
        Label userHelloLabel = new Label("Hello " + userName + "!");

        layout.addComponent(userHelloLabel);

    }

    @WebListener
    public static class MyContextLoaderListener extends ContextLoaderListener {
    }

    @Configuration
    @EnableVaadin
    public static class MyConfiguration {

        @Bean(name="userService")
        public UserService helloWorld() {
            return new UserServiceImpl();
        }

    }

    @WebServlet(urlPatterns = "/*", name = "MyUIServlet", asyncSupported = true)
    @VaadinServletConfiguration(ui = MyUI.class, productionMode = false)
    public static class MyUIServlet extends SpringAwareVaadinServlet {
    }

    private UserService getUserService(VaadinRequest request) {
        WrappedSession session = request.getWrappedSession();
        HttpSession httpSession = ((WrappedHttpSession) session).getHttpSession();
        ServletContext servletContext = httpSession.getServletContext();
        appContext = WebApplicationContextUtils.getRequiredWebApplicationContext(servletContext);

        return (UserService) appContext.getBean("userService");
    }

}
```

Although quite messy (I followed the wiki), the only important things here are the `Vaadin Spring` annotations (`@SpringUI("")`, `@EnableVaadin`, as for the linked tutorial) and some Spring's annotations (beyond the `@Configuration` one I also define a *Spring bean* named "userService" via the `@Bean` annotation inside the `MyConfiguration` class). Please also note that I have a member *transient* field which references Spring's `ApplicationContext` (which I use inside the UI's getUserService(VaadinRequest) method in order to get the "userService" bean).

Here is the code either for the `UserService` interface and for the class `UserServiceImpl`:

```
package com.example.vaadinwithspring;

public class UserService {

    public User getUser();

}

-------------------------------------------------------------------

package com.example.vaadinwithspring;

public class UserServiceImpl implements UserService {

    @Override
    public User getUser() {
        User user = new User();
        user.setName("UserName");
        return user;
    }

}
```

And then, the User class:

```
package com.example.vaadinwithspring;

public class User {

    private String name;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

}
```

All components are dummy implementations, just to see that Vaadin cooperates fine with Spring and that everything works.

Finally, the *Vaadin Spring* tutorial advises to use an `applicationContext.xml` and put it inside src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/ when not using `Spring Boot or JavaConfig`.

I have created the following applicationContext.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.1.xsd">

    <bean class="com.example.vaadinwithspring.MyUI.MyConfiguration" />
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.example.vaadinwithspring" />
</beans>
```

Now, as I said, if I launch the application, everything works great. The only issue I am facing is that `NotSerializableException` related to `XmlWebApplicationContext` when I restart the application.

Why the exception is thrown at all if I have a transient ApplicationContext member which shouldn't be serialized? I suppose that Spring uses another instance of `XmlWebApplicationContext` and uses it internally, is it so? Then:

Is there a way to fix it? How?

Thanks for the attention!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default, Tomcat tries to load sessions from previous run on restart. If it fails loading those sessions (your case), it prints the error to log then it initializes your application normally. Effectively, there is no problem here but you don't get session persistence. Unless you're using a production app, you don't need this functionality.

Some approaches you may take other than simply ignoring it:

1. [Disable session persistence](https://www.google.com/search?q=Disable%20session%20persistence%20Tomcat)
2. Use another container like [Jetty](http://eclipse.org/jetty/), which does not persist sessions by default

I believe the problem comes from [SpringAwareVaadinServlet](https://github.com/vaadin/spring/blob/master/vaadin-spring/src/main/java/com/vaadin/spring/servlet/SpringAwareVaadinServlet.java). It injects your `applicationContext` into the `SpringAwareUIProvider` and it effectively gets stored in persistent session store.

If you really want session persistence with this setup, you need to extend `VaadinServlet` and implement a custom `UIProvider` that does not store `applicationContext` itself but it gets it from another place, possibly a static field in your servlet.